# Python getting input for test cases in competitive coding

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, testcase

How do I take input for T test cases with N values in a list.

Where T is the number of test cases and N is the length of inputs to be taken into a list

```
3
3
2 2 2
3
1 2 3
4
2 3 4 5
```

I want to get out the lists to work on them like:

```
[2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use string's `split` method to separate elements by `' '` (space) and `map` function to convert string input values to integers.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    input()    # gets length of list, but doesn't store it
    input_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(input_list)
```

Comment: how do they get out of the loop?  why take the input and not do anything with the value?

Answer (score 2):

You can take inputs using Python List Comprehension. Input for T test cases with N values in a list. I am using Python 3.x.

```
T = int(input())  #Enter the No. of Testcases
input_list = [[j for j in input().split(' ')] for i in range(T)]
```

Comment: you should note this requires someone to enter the input as "a b c d" for a row

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this script does not do any validation on the input and the length of the test case (i.e. `l`) is not really required.

```
T = int(input())

testCases = []
for i in range(T):
    l = int(input())
    testCase = [int(x) for x in  input().split(" ")]
    testCases.append(testCase)

print(testCases)
```

Comment: what's the point of input `l` when you never use it?

Answer (score 0):

**Python**

```
kases = int(input())
for kase in range(kases):
    N = int(input())
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        result = result * i
    print (result)
```

Comment: this does not answer the question asked or provide a useful solution. please consider deleting your answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
test_case=int(input())
while test_case!=0:
     n=int(input())
     a=list(map(int,input().split()))
     test_case-=1
```

Comment: this is just wrong, its an infinite loop or it never enters.